# Xamarin Android Simulator and sending test GPS data to app

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, gps, xamarin.android

I am using this tutorial ([C#-Corner GPS Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/xamarin-android-working-with-gps-and-locations/)) to get into GPS on Android. I have copied and pasted the whole code into a C# project to be able to see the app working with the emulator which comes with Xamarin.

As I have seen the Emulator has the ability to send GPS data to the underlying Android version to simulate an location change. But the GPS data doesn't seem to get through the emulator to my app.

Is this function really operational or is it just a type of "Hey-here's-a-Button"-Button?

I just want to see if this code will work with this.

Comment: The Xamarin Android Player is deprecated and no longer supported. We created the tool as a much faster version of the old ARM-based Google AVD emulators. However, they have since much improved in performance with the introduction of the x86 images and HAXM. I would strongly recommend using the Google AVD instead of XAP.

Comment: @AlanClark I think I am using the Google AVD. It was pre-installed when I installed Xamarin for VS 2015

Comment: Oh I see. In that case I would probably recommend a) sharing your project here via GitHub and b) see if you experience any difference using a physical device.